# How to get submitted data in the same form in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.0.
I have a form in my project. When I submit a form it return with error. But not getting the posted data.

I have used `{{ old('name') }}`. It is working with perfect. But I want to make a condition with the post data. If I use

```
@if( {{ old('name') }} == "praveen" )
```

it shows error.

I have seen Request::get('name') method one time. But I cannot remember that correctly. Please give me a solution.

Comment: In controller try return Redirect::back()->withInput();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not print in your condition. Just this:

```
@if(old('name') == "praveen")
    // code here
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

to get submitted data in the same form you should use

return Redirect::back()->with('name');